# Giving access through designer gives access to all the lists

Tags: sharepoint-designer

I have a list in SharePoint. The permissions are fine and user is able to access only one list for which he has permission.

In Item Created Workflow I am giving `read` and `edit` permissions to specific users in an impersonation step. After creating an item in the list the user is able to access all other lists in quick launch for which he don't have access to.

What is the issue?

Comment: Unique Permissions of the list disappears once i give unique permission to list item

Comment: Which SharePoint version are you using to create a workflow?

Comment: Sharepoint 2013 foundation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got the reason. In workflow I was removing the permission of the user to the item and then giving permission. So it gives limited access permission to parent list and site. I reversed the order of the steps. it is working fine.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with impersonation with sandbox solution than please check below mentioned reference.

[Sandboxed SharePoint Workflow Actions](http://www.ilovesharepoint.com/2012/06/released-sandboxed-sharepoint-workflow.html)

**NOTE:-** Impersonation steps can only be added to the root of a workflow and cannot be nested in another step.

Comment: List unique permissions are acting weirdly. Is that because the lists are created from same templates